# Pasting Date fomat to suit WorkDay Function

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to change cell format depending on dates and am using `Application.WorksheetFunction.Workday` so I can account for non-working days.

The non-working days have been brought in via a link to a master spreadsheet and it looks like the format does not suit this function as I get a Run-time error 1004 "Unable to get the WorkDay property of the WorksheetFunction.

Does anyone have an idea how I can get this data from another workbook in a format that will work?

I have tried copying the non-working days values to another row, tried all sorts of formatting tricks, even using a named range. All give me same run-time code 1004.

The code works if I remove the `[MPS_Data!Z4:Z100]` or I manually type the dates in so I believe it is a formatting issue only.

Below is a test example of my code, any help would be appreciated.

```
Sub Test()

Dim cell As Range

For Each cell In Sheet1.Range("Traffic_Light_Cells") 'Blank cells
    If cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "" And cell.Value >= Application.WorksheetFunction.WorkDay(Date, 1, [MPS_Data!Z4:Z100]) And cell.Value <= Application.WorksheetFunction.WorkDay(Date, 5, [MPS_Data!Z4:Z100]) Then
        cell.Interior.Color = RGB(188, 253, 175)
        cell.Font.Bold = True
        cell.Font.Color = RGB(84, 130, 53)
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you have an End Sub, but aside from that, your WorkDay function is not like entering the formula into a spreadsheet. You would need to use VBA to call out the range on MPS_data like below:

Instead of: `Application.WorksheetFunction.WorkDay(Date, 1, [MPS_Data!Z4:Z100])`

Try referencing the range like: `Application.WorksheetFunction.WorkDay(Date, 1, Sheets("MPS_data").Range("Z4:Z100"))`

When you get that 1004 error, you probably have a value in the range for holidays that isn't the type that is expected. Check your `MPS_Data!Z4:Z100` for data that isn't a date. I can replicate this error by changing a date in the holiday list to a value of "X"

Comment: Hi Wyatt, Thanks for looking at this for me. Unfortunately after altering the code as you suggest I'm still getting the exact Run-time error 1004 "Unable to get the WorkDay property of the WorksheetFunction."

Comment: Please check your data, based on my edit. if you still have an issue, you can share what your data looks like.

Comment: That's the money - I had checked, re-checked & then triple checked the cells were in date format but it turns out that it was stumbling on a couple of blank cells in the range. When I populated them the macro ran without an issue. thanks again - m.h.